# Does google play store is encrypted?

Tags: android, encryption, google-play

I wonder to know, when downloading an application using google play store mobile app, does the downloaded data is encrypted or not?

If it does, since when?

Comment: Your question is not precise. You could download encrypted apks over an unencrypted channel (I don't say this makes sense, but your question is vague)

Comment: The app store also uses https for SSL/TLS encryption

Comment: For which case? downloading?

Comment: Well yes. TSL stands for Transport Layer Security. Anything going over the network will be encrypted using HTTPS encryption.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **App Encryption**
>
> Starting with Android 4.1, Google Play will help protect application
>   assets by encrypting all paid apps with a device-specific key before
>   they are delivered and stored on a device.

reference: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/32306/security-of-paid-apps-in-google-play

Comment: I'm asking about all the downloading process (free/paid app), is it encrypted?

Comment: @TheDr. I'm fairly sure this is covered by this answer...